# how to post a message on facebook user wall after permission granted by user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post on user wall with user id,After permission granted by user,how to post a message on users wall without access token?

Comment: developers.facebook.com

Comment: on which section of the developers.facebook.com describe about the issue reported (post a message on users wall without access token?),i tried a lot but not getting anything

Comment: You can't just randomly post crap on people's "walls". You need their permission first.

Comment: my question is that,After permission granted by user,how to post a message on users wall without access token? and 1 thing when i am posting a message it is also displaying friend wall,how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After permission granted by user,how to post a message on users wall without access token

Use the **APP ACCESS TOKEN** (APP_ID|APP_SECRET) for your call

```
\POST /<user-id>/feed  // with required parameters
```

Comment: how can i show callback response after posting a message,means success or failure..? please reply

Comment: take the response of the call in a variable, say `$response` and you'll get the POST_ID in return or an error object; so you can check accordingly! And pls accept/mark the answer if helped. Good luck!

Comment: You can post another question with the proper details and screenshots